# Who are these ghosts that visit Dan?

Tags: doctor-sleep

Somewhere during the movie, Dan sees the ghost of a women and her kid.

[image]

It is after he leaves a drug-user mom, her kid, and after he considers stealing her money (although I thought it was implied he actually **did not**). The ghost says something like

> They haven't found us yet.

Who are these ghosts? Is it the women he slept with? Is it implying he took her money and they died?

Answer (score 2):

It was the girl he slept with at the beginning. He did take his money back from her.  He used it later at the bus station to see how far he could get away from there. I think the girl probably died later from the cocaine she was doing. She was telling him because she always leaves her boy at home and hes alone that he is always crying and the neighbors just figured he was crying like always and didn't help him. So when she overdosed no one came to help the boy. Then she ended with, "They haven't found us yet."